# Performance issue with python - how to find and work on matching records from data in long format

Tags: python, r, performance

Suppose you have a data frame `AllData` looking like:

```
     ID M   P
1  ID_4 D 4.9
2  ID_1 A 5.0
3  ID_3 D 5.0
4  ID_5 D 5.1
5  ID_2 B 5.2
6  ID_1 B 5.5
7  ID_3 A 6.0
8  ID_1 C 6.0
9  ID_4 B 6.3
10 ID_4 A 6.5
11 ID_5 A 7.0
12 ID_3 C 7.0
13 ID_5 C 8.0
```

For each *pair* of distinct values of `M` (order does not matter), you want to find the records having matching `ID`'s, and calculate: the number of such records, the min and max value for their `P`'s and the Spearman correlation coefficient between their `P`'s.

E.g. if you cross-tabulate the above in `R`:

```
xtabs(P ~ ID + M, AllData, sparse = T)

      M
ID       A   B C   D
  ID_1 5.0 5.5 6 .  
  ID_2 .   5.2 . .  
  ID_3 6.0 .   7 5.0
  ID_4 6.5 6.3 . 4.9
  ID_5 7.0 .   8 5.1
```

you see that A and D have 3 `ID`'s in common, with `P` going from 6.0 to 7.0 for A, and from 4.9 to 5.1 for D; the Spearman correlation coefficient is 0.5:

```
cor(c(6.0, 6.5, 7.0), c(5.0, 4.9, 5.1), method = 'spearman')
#[1] 0.5
```

I had coded this kind of calculations in `R`, and I was OK with the performance.
Now I tried to reproduce the same in `python`, and I suspect I did something wrong, because it's something like 10 times slower.
Most often `python` is at least as fast as `R`, if not faster, hence my puzzlement.

See below the code examples with timings.
Keeping in mind that the real data I am using is **much** sparser than this, I can report that the difference in performance is similar (about 2.5 min in `R`, about 20-25 min in `python`).

**Would anyone be able to suggest improvements for the python version?**

My impression is that the part where the `ID`'s in common are determined is the critical one.
In that respect, I've already tried a few things, like completely bypassing the explicit identification of the records in common, i.e. making a sparse cross-tabulated matrix and using the `nan_policy = 'omit'` of `spearmanr`; or using `np.isin`, `np.intersect1d` and similar instead of the dict keys logical operation I used here.
None of these approaches improved the performance.

`R` code:

```
AllData = data.frame(
  "ID" = paste0('ID_', c(1,3,4,5,1,2,4,1,3,5,3,4,5)),
  "M" = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D'),
  "P" = c(5,6,6.5,7,5.5,5.2,6.3,6,7,8,5,4.9,5.1)
)

AllData = AllData[order(AllData$P), ]

rownames(AllData) <- 1:(dim(AllData)[1])

#xtabs(P ~ ID + M, AllData)

# Replace ID with an index of its sorted elements
AllData['ID'] <- as.numeric(factor(AllData[['ID']]))

# Replace M with an index of its elements
M.u <- unique(AllData[['M']])
M.u.N <- length(M.u)
M.u <- sort(M.u)
AllData[['M']] <- as.numeric(factor(AllData[['M']], levels = as.character(M.u)))

# Sort AllData by the numeric index obtained from ID
AllData = AllData[order(AllData$M, AllData$ID),]

# Create a matrix of ID indices and matching P values, for each M.u
M.ind.pos <- unname(c(1, 1 + cumsum(table(AllData[['M']]))))
ID.vs.M <- sapply(1:M.u.N,
                  FUN = function(ci) {
                    AllData[(M.ind.pos[ci]):(M.ind.pos[ci+1] - 1), c('ID', 'P')]})

# Calculate Spearman correlation and stats

ts <- numeric(0)

for (xx in 1:7) {
  
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  
  for (x in 1:1000) {
    
    cor.out <- vector("list", M.u.N * (M.u.N - 1) / 2)
    r <- 0
    
    for (i in 1:(M.u.N - 1)) {
      #print(paste0(i, "/", (M.u.N - 1), ", ", M.u[i]))
      rvi <- ID.vs.M[,i]
      ri <- rvi[[1]]
      vi <- rvi[[2]]
      Ni <- length(vi)
      
      for (j in (i+1):(M.u.N)) {
        rvj <- ID.vs.M[,j]
        rj <- rvj[[1]]
        vj <- rvj[[2]]
        Nj <- length(vj)
        
        ri_in_rj <- which(ri %in% rj)
        vi_ij <- vi[ri_in_rj]
        ri_ij <- ri[ri_in_rj]
        rj_in_ri <- which(rj %in% ri_ij)
        vj_ij <- vj[rj_in_ri]
        
        Nij <- length(ri_in_rj)
        
        Ni.frac <- round(Nij / Ni, 2)
        Nj.frac <- round(Nij / Nj, 2)
        
        vi.range <- as.numeric(c(NA, NA))
        vj.range <- as.numeric(c(NA, NA))
        vi.range.diff <- as.numeric(NA)
        vj.range.diff <- as.numeric(NA)
        cor.ij <- as.numeric(NA)
        
        if (Nij >= 1) {
          vi.range <- range(vi_ij)
          vj.range <- range(vj_ij)
          vi.range.diff <- diff(vi.range)
          vj.range.diff <- diff(vj.range)
        }
        
        if (Nij >= 3) {
          cor.ij <- cor(vi_ij, vj_ij, method = 'spearman')
        }
        
        # Add result to the list
        r <- r + 1
        cor.out[[r]] <- c(i, j, Ni, Nj, Nij, vi.range, vi.range.diff, vj.range, vj.range.diff, cor.ij)
      }
    }
  }
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  ts <- c(ts, as.numeric(end_time - start_time))
}

# time in s for 1000 runs = time in ms for 1 run
print(paste0("7 x 1000 repeats: ", mean(ts), " +/- ", sd(ts), " ms"))
```

result:

```
7 x 1000 repeats: 0.364144154957363 +/- 0.0251607071478284 ms
```

`python` code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

AllData = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID" : ['ID_'+ str(i) for i in [1,3,4,5,1,2,4,1,3,5,3,4,5]],
    "M" : ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D'],
    "P" : [5,6,6.5,7,5.5,5.2,6.3,6,7,8,5,4.9,5.1]
})

AllData = AllData.sort_values('P').reset_index(drop = True)

# Make a numerical index for ID, as a dict
unique_IDs = AllData['ID'].unique()
index_vs_ID_dict = dict(zip(unique_IDs, range(len(unique_IDs))))

# Make a dict of (index, P) vs M
index_P_vs_M_dict = dict()

for M, ID, P in zip(AllData['M'].values, AllData['ID'].values, AllData['P'].values) :
    index = index_vs_ID_dict[ID]
    if M not in index_P_vs_M_dict :
        index_P_vs_M_dict[M] = [(index, P)]
    else :
        index_P_vs_M_dict[M].append((index, P))

# Turn each list of tuples in index_P_vs_M_dict into a dict of P vs index
for k in index_P_vs_M_dict :    
    index_P_vs_M_dict[k] = dict(index_P_vs_M_dict[k])

M_list = list(index_P_vs_M_dict.keys())

%%timeit

corr_table = pd.DataFrame()

for m, M1 in enumerate(M_list[:-1]) :  
  # Read the index_P dictionary of M1
  d1 = index_P_vs_M_dict[M1]
  # Extract the index of M1 as dict keys
  i1 = d1.keys()  
  N1 = len(i1)
  #print(M1, ", ", str(N1))

  for M2 in M_list[(m+1):] :
    # Read the index_P dictionary of M2
    d2 = index_P_vs_M_dict[M2]
    # Extract the index of M1 as dict keys
    i2 = d2.keys()
    N2 = len(i2)

    # Find the indices in common between M1 and M2    
    i12 = (i1 & i2)
    N12 = len(i12)
    
    # Compute the srcc and stats
    srcc = pd.NA
    if (N12 > 2) :
      a1 = [d1[index] for index in i12]
      a2 = [d2[index] for index in i12]
      min_a1 = min(a1)
      max_a1 = max(a1)
      range_a1 = max_a1 - min_a1
      min_a2 = min(a2)
      max_a2 = max(a2)
      range_a2 = max_a2 - min_a2
      if (range_a1 > 0) & (range_a2 > 0) :
        srcc = spearmanr(a1, a2)[0]
        #print(M2 + ', # ID\'s in common = ' + str(N12) + ', SRCC = ' + str(srcc))                
    else:
      min_a1 = pd.NA
      max_a1 = pd.NA
      range_a1 = pd.NA        
      min_a2 = pd.NA
      max_a2 = pd.NA
      range_a2 = pd.NA      
    
    if True:
      # Store the results in corr_table
      corr_table = pd.concat([corr_table, pd.DataFrame({
        "M_1" : M1,
        "M_2" : M2,
        "N_1" : N1,
        "N_2" : N2,
        "N_common_IDs" : N12,
        "min_1" : min_a1,
        "max_1" : max_a1,
        "range_1" : range_a1,
        "min_2" : min_a2,
        "max_2" : max_a2,
        "range_2" : range_a2,
        "Spearman_cc" : srcc
      }, index = [0])], axis = 0)
```

result:

```
4.73 ms ± 11.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Looks like a bit more than 10 times slower than `R`, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use a library of mine - **convtools** ([github](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools)) to build the grouper.

```py
from itertools import combinations

from scipy.stats import spearmanr
from convtools import conversion as c


input_data = {
    "ID": ["ID_" + str(i) for i in [1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5]],
    "M": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"],
    "P": [5, 6, 6.5, 7, 5.5, 5.2, 6.3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4.9, 5.1],
}
# let's rewrite as list of dicts
prepared_data = [
    dict(zip(("ID", "M", "P"), tuple_))
    for tuple_ in zip(input_data["ID"], input_data["M"], input_data["P"])
]

# build the grouper
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("M"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "M": c.item("M"),
            # this assumes you only have a single value per ID, otherwise
            # replace with DictArray and handle accordingly
            "id_to_p_values": c.ReduceFuncs.Dict(c.item("ID"), c.item("P")),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter()
)

# In [18]: converter(prepared_data)
# Out[18]:
# [{'M': 'A', 'id_to_p_values': {'ID_1': 5, 'ID_3': 6, 'ID_4': 6.5, 'ID_5': 7}},
#  {'M': 'B', 'id_to_p_values': {'ID_1': 5.5, 'ID_2': 5.2, 'ID_4': 6.3}},
#  {'M': 'C', 'id_to_p_values': {'ID_1': 6, 'ID_3': 7, 'ID_5': 8}},
#  {'M': 'D', 'id_to_p_values': {'ID_3': 5, 'ID_4': 4.9, 'ID_5': 5.1}}]


def calculate_pair(left, right):
    left_id_to_p_values = left["id_to_p_values"]
    right_id_to_p_values = right["id_to_p_values"]
    common_keys = set(left_id_to_p_values).intersection(right_id_to_p_values)
    left_p_values = [left_id_to_p_values[key] for key in common_keys]
    right_p_values = [right_id_to_p_values[key] for key in common_keys]

    min_1 = min(left_p_values)
    min_2 = min(right_p_values)
    max_1 = max(left_p_values)
    max_2 = max(right_p_values)
    return {
        "M1": left["M"],
        "M2": right["M"],
        "N1": len(left_id_to_p_values),
        "N2": len(right_id_to_p_values),
        "min_1": min_1,
        "min_2": min_2,
        "max_1": max_1,
        "max_2": max_2,
        "range_1": max_1 - min_1,
        "range_2": max_2 - min_2,
        "N_common_IDs": len(common_keys),
        "srcc": spearmanr(left_p_values, right_p_values)[0],
    }


%%timeit
results = [
    calculate_pair(left, right)
    for left, right in combinations(converter(prepared_data), 2)
]
# 457 µs ± 1.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# results == [
#     {'M1': 'A', 'M2': 'B', 'N1': 4, 'N2': 3, 'min_1': 5, 'min_2': 5.5, 'max_1': 6.5, 'max_2': 6.3, 'range_1': 1.5, 'range_2': 0.7999999999999998, 'N_common_IDs': 2, 'srcc': 0.9999999999999999},
#     {'M1': 'A', 'M2': 'C', 'N1': 4, 'N2': 3, 'min_1': 5, 'min_2': 6, 'max_1': 7, 'max_2': 8, 'range_1': 2, 'range_2': 2, 'N_common_IDs': 3, 'srcc': 1.0},
#     {'M1': 'A', 'M2': 'D', 'N1': 4, 'N2': 3, 'min_1': 6, 'min_2': 4.9, 'max_1': 7, 'max_2': 5.1, 'range_1': 1, 'range_2': 0.1999999999999993, 'N_common_IDs': 3, 'srcc': 0.5},
#     {'M1': 'B', 'M2': 'C', 'N1': 3, 'N2': 3, 'min_1': 5.5, 'min_2': 6, 'max_1': 5.5, 'max_2': 6, 'range_1': 0.0, 'range_2': 0, 'N_common_IDs': 1, 'srcc': nan},
#     {'M1': 'B', 'M2': 'D', 'N1': 3, 'N2': 3, 'min_1': 6.3, 'min_2': 4.9, 'max_1': 6.3, 'max_2': 4.9, 'range_1': 0.0, 'range_2': 0.0, 'N_common_IDs': 1, 'srcc': nan},
#     {'M1': 'C', 'M2': 'D', 'N1': 3, 'N2': 3, 'min_1': 7, 'min_2': 5, 'max_1': 8, 'max_2': 5.1, 'range_1': 1, 'range_2': 0.09999999999999964, 'N_common_IDs': 2, 'srcc': 0.9999999999999999}
# ]
```

Unfortunately we cannot compare my `457 µs` to your `4.73ms` as you timed only a part of your data processing procedure (and of course we have different hardware).

Comment: This is great, thanks! I will try it asap.
I will time the whole process when I try; but in fact this was under the assumption that the initial preparation is very quick compared to the ID matching and other calculations.

Comment: Tests done. I used another machine, and I started the time measurement in each case at the start of the handling of the original data (for R and my own python, I defined AllData0 and copied it to AllData as the first step; for the convtools-based python, just before # let's...). Results: R: 7 x 1000 repeats: 0.546141726630075 +/- 0.0112169068998369 ms; my python: 3.84 ms ± 49.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each); convtools-based python: 1.58 ms ± 9.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each). I need to try on the original machine.

Comment: You can generate convtools converter once and use it multiple times (just like you define functions). So this part can be excluded from testing and considered as a warm-up phase.

Comment: True, but normally I process only one (large) dataset in one session, not many similar ones in sequence; so the time required to make the converter is part of the total time I need to spend in practice. I am going to test your method on the real large dataset. If it performs as good as R, great. I will already accept your answer, as in any case you proved you can get a performance close to 0.5x speed compared to R, which per se is good enough. Thanks again!

Comment: Good, glad to help! In case of "the real large dataset": consider replacing list comprehension for "prepared_data" with a generator comprehension (not to build the list before the grouper kicks in; the grouper can consume an iterable -- this will reduce memory usage).